# SELECT com busca de palavras chave

Tags: mysql

Como fazer um `SELECT` com campos específicos e utilizando `LIKE %%` na mesma instrução? algo parecido com:
`SELECT TABLE_A.COLUMN1, TABLE_A.COLUMN2 FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN2 LIKE 'A%'`

ja tentei isso mais não retorna nada.

Comment: Como estão os dados na sua tabela? Dê um exemplo do que quer retornar

Comment: tenho uma tabela `Administrator` com os campos `idAdm`, `userName`,`level` e `userPass`, gostaria de fazer a pesquisa assim: `SELECT Administrator.userPass, Administrator.userName FROM Administrator WHERE userName LIKE = "c%";` porem ele não retorna, mais se eu removo as tabelas e coloco `*` traz normal.

Comment: Existe algum usuário com começando com `c` minusculo ou é maiúsculo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O comando SELECT não me parece mal.
Isto se o intuito é seleccionar registos onde a COLUMN2 tenha valores começados por a letra **A** maíuscula.
A síntaxe do LIKE é simples:

- **%** é uma wildcard. Serve para representar 0, 1 ou N caracteres
- **_** é um *placeholder*. Serve para representar 1 e apenas 1 qualquer caractere

Ao usar o padrão **A%** estamos a condicionar os resultados a qualquer valor começado por **A**, ou apenas **A**

- A `OK`
- Andreia `OK`
- André `OK`
- arara `NÃO OK`
- Macaco `NÃO OK`

Para ignorar as maiúsculas ou minúsculas, assumindo que a tabela ou o campo estão configurados para serem *Case Sensitive*, basta reduzir ambos a um dos cases, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE LOWER(COLUNA) LIKE 'a%'
```

A wildcard pode ser repetida. Por exemplo, se quisermos restringir aos nomes que contenham um **A** em qualquer posição:

```
LIKE '%a%'
```

Uma verificação de email (rudimentar):

```
LIKE '%_@_%._%'
```

Com um mínimo de 3 caracteres:

```
LIKE '___%'
```

E por aí fora.

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão Sérgio, não é mais fácil fazer direto `LIKE 'a%'` ao invés de chamar a função `LOWER`?

Comment: É, sim. O LOWER na parte do LIKE apenas garante normalização no caso de estar a ser passada por variável. Se por exemplo o "a" fosse indicado por o utilizador.
Neste caso, pode-se omitir o LOWER do LIKE, mas não da coluna.

Comment: Não sou nenhum expert em banco, mas penso que pra cada registro ele irá executar a função pra fazer a comparação, não? Por isso apontei isso

Comment: Podemos sempre normalizar o valor, mesmo que variável, antes de o passar para a construção da query, sim... Vou editar a resposta, só para não deixar essa dúvida a quem possa vir a consultar.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o identificador Administrator.userName no WHERE, talvez possa ser por isso, que ele não esta identificando direito

```
SELECT Administrator.userPass, Administrator.userName
FROM Administrator
WHERE Administrator.userName LIKE "c%"
```

Comment: Não é obrigatório isso Lucas, como nesse contexto só existe uma tabela com a coluna `userName` não se torna obrigatório, pois não tem ambiguidade.

Comment: Falei isso porque não sei todo o contexto do banco e seus relacionamento, mas de certa forma sempre gosto de colocar para não ter problemas.